# I'm having trouble finding a string within a scraped item

Tags: python, scrapy

I've got a very simple spider but when I try to search the contents of the item I'm scraping, it's not being found

The url being scraped:
https://www.filmlinc.org/nyff2019/films/the-irishman/

the spider

```
import scrapy
from metrograph.items import MetrographItem


class MetrographSpider(scrapy.Spider): #**************Change This*****************
    name = 'metrograph' #**************Change This*****************

    start_urls = ['https://www.filmlinc.org/nyff2019/films/the-irishman/',
        ]

    def parse(self, response):

            title=response.xpath('//div[7]//a[1]//span[1]/text()').getall()
            )
            if "Standby" in item['title']:
                print(item['title'])

            yield item
```

But the spider doesn't find the word "Standby" in the scraped field. However, if I manually get it to `print(item['title'])`

I get the following, which clearly has the word in it. I've removed some empty spaces

```
['\n    \n  
 \n\n   Standby Only\n  ']
```

I'm not sure why I'm having trouble? Is the title item a list? Is there a way to search it properly? Eventually the spider will be looking for a scenario when "Standby" is NOT found, but it's obviously I can't do that just yet, if it makes a difference in any possible suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to find a string in the list which looks for entire item while all you need a string to cast the list into str

```
"Standby" in str(['\n    \n  \n\n   Standby Only\n  '])
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had tried converting it to a string but guess not. Thanks again, ```if "Standby" in str(item['title'])``` works perfectly